# Why does String#localeCompare put "ʻ" (ʻOkina) between H and I?

Tags: javascript, unicode, localization, internationalization, ecma

### Background

`ʻ`, the [ʻOkina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOkina), Unicode code point `U+02BB MODIFIER LETTER TURNED COMMA`, is:

> a unicameral consonant letter used within the Latin script to mark the phonemic glottal stop, in many Polynesian languages

Not to be confused with `'` or even `‘`, which are straight and curly single-quotation marks, respectively.

### Question

Why does this:

```js
[...'hiʻ'].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).join('')
```

Yield `hʻi` as its answer? In other words, on what basis does `localeCompare` judge that the ʻOkina comes after H and before I in the alphabet?

The [ECMAScript standard](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-collator-comparestrings) simply mentions that "The two Strings are compared in an implementation-defined fashion", yet both Chromium and Firefox are in agreement about this ordering, at least in the `en-US` locale.

It seems most (all?) languages that include `‘` in their alphabets simply place it at the end. Is there some Unicode standard somewhere that defines alphabetical ordering that both Chromium and Firefox use? Or if not, where did they both get the idea that `‘` falls between H and I?

Comment: Really strange. I master javascript, but this is more like an encoding standard which I don't know. I checked Character Codes, and they are close to your expectations: `'ʻ'.charCodeAt(); // 699`, `'h'.charCodeAt(); // 104`, `'i'.charCodeAt(); // 105` . You might need to use character code to make the comparison.

Comment: @KeitelDOG - Yeah, "collation" is a big topic and not even necessarily related to Unicode code points, much less the code units you see from `charCodeAt`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Wow**, that is really interesting placement.

> Is there some Unicode standard somewhere that defines alphabetical ordering that both Chromium and Firefox use?

Yes. Collation (as it's called) is a **big** topic. It's covered in various places by Unicode, for instance in [Unicode Technical Report 10](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/) and at least in part in [TR15](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html). I haven't found a specific rationale for how the ʻOkina is handled, but in general as I understand it the rules are designed to ensure that a locale (not just language) can specify how characters are collated in that locale.

That doesn't necessarily mean the placement will make sense in an English-speaking locale like en-US or en-GB, but hopefully in a locale properly supporting Polynesian languages, it would be collated in a way that makes sense.

I'm not sure this is an *answer* so much as a pointer to where to find one. I wish I could point to the specific reason. I'm sure there is one, it hasn't just been put there randomly. It (the reason) will likely be in the collation data files in a comment. Or a native speaker might be able to say off the top of their head "Well of course that's where it goes, because ________."

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't know much on it. I should take a dive when I have some free time to understand more about it.

Comment: @KeitelDOG Make sure you have extra oxygen, you may be down there for a while.

Comment: Useful links! Technical Report 10 [references](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/#Allkeys) the "[Default Unicode Collation Element Table](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/14.0.0/allkeys.txt)", which does indeed place MODIFIER LETTER TURNED COMMA, along with MODIFIER LETTER REVERSED COMMA, between H (and variants) and I. So that at least answers the proximate cause, though not the ultimate one. As for ultimate cause... I guess you could argue that the glottal stop is a somewhat "H-like" sound, given that "h" is also typically produced glottally.